# How to incrementally upload video to Youtube

Tags: video, youtube, video-streaming, youtube-api

Is it possible to incrementally upload a video to Youtube programmatically, possibly while the video is being recorded frame by frame? Certain iOS/Android apps claim to support this feature, such as [Qik Video](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.qik.android), but I haven't been able to find any open source reference code that'll run on a generic PC. I'm researching the feasibility of implementing a video surveillance application that can upload its video in realtime to various video sharing sites in case the recording device is compromised.

I've reviewed [Youtube's API](http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Uploading_Videos), and it mentions a [resumable upload process](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol?hl=fr-FR#Resumable_uploads), but it seems more geared towards handling unplanned interrupts, and not controlled pauses in the upload.

Edit: Youtube supposedly [supports streaming of live video](http://techlunatic.com/2011/04/live-stream-youtube-videos/), but I can't find libraries or documentation of how to use this.